# htaccess rewrite rule for subdomain results to redirect loop

Tags: .htaccess, loops, mod-rewrite, redirect, subdomain

Below is my htaccess config

```
    RewriteEngine On

    # if the domain starts with "apply."
    # i.e. apply.domain.com
    # redirect to application URI
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^apply\. [NC]
    RewriteRule !^formwizard /formwizard/apply [R=301,L,NC]
```

I have tried it, and when I go to http://apply.domain.com/ it successfully redirects to http://apply.domain.com/formwizard/apply.
My problem is, once it redirects to that URI, it goes to a redirect loop.
Can anyone please help hit me what is wrong with my config?

**Background:**
I have 3 subdomains: *www.domain.com*, *apply.domain.com*, and *admin.domain.com*. It all references to the same source codes and just managed by my htaccess.
Once the person goes to apply.domain.com, it should be redirected to the application page which is /formwizard/apply.

PS. I don't want to depend too much on the backend codes because I believe this is a server config problem.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is this the only rule or you have more rules not shown here?

Comment: I have other rules in use, but I comment them out before I test this rule. Somehow, only the negate pattern does this.

Answer (score 1):

If there are more rules then this rule might be getting impacted by them. Modify this rule to this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^apply\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/formwizard/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /formwizard/apply [R=301,L,NC]
```

Also make sure this is very first rule below `RewriteEngine On` line.

Comment: I already tried that. weird thing is it always goes to an infinite loop. I also added [L] flag so the other rules will be ignored

Comment: Test with just this rule in root .htaccess and remove all other .htaccess in sub directories. Also test in a new browser or clear browser cache